# Deploy a service before deploying a portlet

Tags: service, liferay, builder

I have to design a service builder in Liferay which retrieve data for the look and feel. Then this service have to deploy before deploying look and feel. I don't know how to deploy  this service. Actually, I obtain an exception of type "no bean named...is defined".

Thank you in advance,

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare dependencies in WEB-INF/liferay-plugin-package.properties. The easiest way to do it is to look it up in other plugins or use Liferay IDE or Developer Studio to edit the file as it comes with a form-based editor, recognizing the file content.

This dependency will make sure that the plugin containing your service will deploy before everything else that depends on it. Dependent plugins will not be deployed until their dependencies are satisfied.

From the sample file [here](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/definitions/liferay-plugin-package_6_1_0.properties):

```
#
# Specify other plugins that depend on deployment of this plugin. Some
# plugins require this in order to rely on services and features provided by
# other plugins.
#
#required-deployment-contexts=
#required-deployment-contexts=\
# chat-portlet,\
# flash-portlet,\
# sample-service-builder-portlet
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I tried this and I add the attribut "requirement context dependancies" but it doesn't work. What' other attribute can I use in liferay-plugin-package.

Comment: edited my answer. was your spelling in the comment a typo? Otherwise, just copy/paste the property name from the answer and try again.